# flashing yocto image to raspberrypi-cm3

Tags: yocto

I have created an image with yocto for **raspberrypi-cm3** architecture 
with eMMC storage.
The generated image are stored in folder *tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi-cm3/* ([attached photo showing content of such directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcGQA.png)).
I have this solution to create a .img to flashed to the eMMC:

```
dd bs=512 count=2880 if=/dev/zero of=raspberry-cm3.img
mkfs.msdos raspberry-cm3.img
mkdir raspberrypi
sudo mount -o loop raspberry-cm3.img raspberrypi
cp -r /deploy/images/raspberry-cm3/* raspberrypi
sudo umount raspberrypi
```

But I am wondering shouldn't I first leave a space for the boot partition ?

Comment: Such image is already prepared and You don't need to carry about boot partition.

Comment: offtopic: get rid of count key, and increase bs to, say 4M

Comment: Note you can use [bmaptool](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#flashing-images-using-bmaptool) to speedup image flashing.