# flashing yocto image to cm3 emmc

Tags: yocto, flashing

I am new to yocto world and i am trying to build a custom image for raspberrypi-cm3.
i have built the image with no errors and i have a generated image folder in the attached photo,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u36V.png) that contains multiple files  that are confusing me such as

rpi-basic-image-raspberrypi-cm3.rootfs.tar.bz2

rpi-basic-image-raspberrypi-cm3.rootfs.ext3

image-kernelversion-machine.bin

rpi-basic-image-raspberrypi-cm3.rootfs.rpi-sdimg

bootcode.bin

and .dtb, .dtbo files

Now i am trying to understand what files are to be flashed to my emmc? how the boot partition will be created?

I have searched and found that i should create a .img where i copy all the files and flash it to the emmc.
But i am wondering how the emmc will be partionned.
As i knew  there must be a boot partition and a rootfs partition.

i hope someone can explain to me how does the yocto images should be flashed on the emmc and what files should be considered.

Comment: Please update your previous thread instead of creating new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flashing yocto image to raspberrypi-cm3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272528/flashing-yocto-image-to-raspberrypi-cm3)

Answer (score 0):

Generated with *meta-raspberrypi* metadata layer binary file is - **rpi-basic-image-raspberrypi-cm3.rootfs.rpi-sdimg**, ready to install without any additional modification, so please try install it on Your eMMC:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdX
sudo dd if=tmp/deploy/images/rpi-basic-image-raspberrypi-cm3.rootfs.rpi-sdimg bs=4M of=/dev/sdX    
sudo umount /dev/sdX
```